# GoogleAppEngineでユーザー毎にページ閲覧を制限する方法について

Tags: google-app-engine

現在GAEにて登録制のウェブページのようなものを作りたく、
(なんらかの登録を行った)特定のgoogleアカウントのみページ閲覧を許可するということを試みています。

google app engineの設定画面＞設定＞アプリケーションの設定＞Google認証
にてgoogleアカウントにログインしていないとページ閲覧を制限できることはわかったのですが、
これですとGoogleアカウントにログインしてしまえば全ユーザーがログインできることになってしまいますし、
ロールもAdminと一般のものしかないようです。

上記のような用途の場合、自前で以下を用意する必要がありますでしょうか？
・登録ページのフロントエンド
・登録したユーザーの管理(datastore等での管理でしょうか？)
・ページアクセス時のアカウント確認(ページアクセス毎にappengine/user IFを使用して確認する形になりますでしょうか？datastoreの管理情報との照らし合わせることも考えるとパフォーマンスも懸念しています。)

Googleのサービスをあまり理解しておらず、
なにか既存の仕組みを使って出来るようであればご教示いただきたく思います。

また、自前でユーザー管理を行うとしてもセオリーのようなものがありましたらご教示いただきたく思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下の考えで合っています。
毎回Datastoreにアクセスするとパフォーマンス低下と、DatastoreのReadOpsが増える問題があるので、Memcache https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/memcache/ を活用するとよいです。

> 登録したユーザーの管理(datastore等での管理でしょうか？)
>   ページアクセス時のアカウント確認(ページアクセス毎にappengine/user IFを使用して確認する形になりますでしょうか？datastoreの管理情報との照らし合わせることも考えるとパフォーマンスも懸念しています。)

Comment: ありがとうございます。なにかGoogleのAPI等用いてできないかと思っておりましたが、さすがにそのあたりは自前での管理が必要なのですね。